# Unable to open ADODB recordset (with password)

Tags: ms-access, vba, adodb

I have the below code to open a connection to another Access database and then open a recordset

```
Sub OpenTest()
Dim Acon As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset

 With Acon
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "C:\MyFolder\MyDb.accdb"
    .Properties("Jet OLEDB:Database Password") = "OpenSesame"
    .Open
 End With

 Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
 rst.Open "SELECT * FROM tblAdmin", Acon, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly

 If rst.EOF = False Or rst.BOF = False Then
    rst.MoveFirst
    Debug.Print rst!UserID
 End If

 Set rst = Nothing
 Acon.Close
End Sub
```

The connections itself opens fine but then strangely the recordset fails to open and I get a run time error saying

> Not a valid password

The password is definitely correct (as evidenced by the connection opening). When setting the password on the database I ensured that the legacy encryption option was selected for compatability. I have also used this code to open a different database and it works fine.

Does anybody have any idea why it may not be working?

Comment: Have you tried using `Set rst = Acon.Execute(query)`?

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. I've tried that but unfortunately I'm still getting the same error message

Comment: The connection truly opens when the connection is first used. Not getting an error on `.Open` doesn't mean your password is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure that's the case as if I put the incorrect password then the connection fails to open but with the correct password then it fails on the line which opens the recordset. I have opened the database myself and entered the password to ensure it is correct

Comment: Are you using user-level security on the database, by any chance? That way you can have two, different passwords. Alternatively, you can try the current code with an ODBC connection string

Comment: There isn't any user-level security. It turns out I couldn't open the recordset on a linked table. I had to provide the file path for the actual back end. So simple in the end but I had been stuck for ages. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that is interested. I found the problem. It was just because the table I was trying to use in the recordset was actually a linked table. I changed the file path to the one for the back end and it now works fine.

ヾ(`ヘ´)ﾉﾞ